# Is this fractional equation true for all real numbers?

Tags: fractions

Is this equation true for all real values of $a,b,c,x,y,z$?

If $$\frac{a}{x} = \frac{b}{y} = \frac{c}{z} = t$$

Then $$\frac{a+b+c}{x+y+z} = t$$

I've tried experimenting with several values and they make an equality, but does this equation hold true for all real values?

Comment: of course not just take $a=b=0$ $c=tz$ and $x=y=10000000000$

Comment: Ah, the old bait and switch hahahah. Maybe it was a genuine typo though as "+" is the same key as "=".

Comment: Please do *not* edit your question in a way that invalidates existing (valid) answers. Instead, you should ask a fresh question.

Comment: You just edit the question. Answers after this edit now seems like invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Almost always) yes: from the first set of equations, you have $a=xt, b=yt, c=zt$. Therefore,

$$\frac{a+b+c}{x+y+z} = \frac{xt+yt+zt}{x+y+z} = t\frac{x+y+z}{x+y+z} = t$$
provided, of course, that $x+y+z\neq 0$.

---

An example of this: imagine a course where you're graded on homework, a midterm, and an exam. If you get the same grade on each of these components, then that's your final grade, regardless of how they're weighted.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach that is somewhat inferior to the approach
taken in Theophile's answer.

It is assumed that none of $a,b,c,x,y,z, (x + y + z)$ are equal to zero.

Without loss of generality, there exist (Real non-zero) scalars $r,s$
such that $a = rb$ and c = sb$.$

Therefore, $\frac{rb}{x} = \frac{b}{y} \implies \frac{r}{x} = \frac{1}{y} \implies
x = ry$.  Similarly, $z = sy.$

Therefore, $\frac{a + b + c}{x + y + z} = \frac{b(r + 1 + s)}{y(r + 1 + s)}.$

Note that the assumption that $(r + 1 + s) = 0$ would imply that 
$(x + y + z) = y(r + 1 + s) = 0$, which is a contradiction.

Therefore, you know that

$\frac{b(r + 1 + s)}{y(r + 1 + s)} = \frac{b}{y} = t.$

Answer (score -1):

$ \text{Not true for all real numbers}  $

Comparing both equations,

$ \frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{y}+\frac{c}{z}= \frac{a+b+c}{x+y+z} $

$ (x+y+z)\times (\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{y}+\frac{c}{z})=a+b+c $

$ \frac{1}{x} (ax+ay+az) + \frac{1}{y}(bx+by+bz) + \frac{1}{z}(cx+cy+cz) = a+b+c$

$ a+\frac{ay+az}{x} +b+ \frac{bx+bz}{y} + c+ \frac{cx+cy}{z}=a+b+c $

$a+b+c= a+b+c +(\frac{ay+az}{x} + \frac{bx+bz}{y} + \frac{cx+cy}{z}) $

$ \frac{ay+az}{x} + \frac{bx+bz}{y} + \frac{cx+cy}{z} = 0 $

$ \text{As} $ $ x,y,z \neq 0  $

one Solution is when  $ a=b=c=0 $, and have other solutions as well but Not true for all Real Numbers.

Thanks to

Comment: The problem was updated; the question is different now. But even for the original question, your argument doesn't make sense. How can you conclude that $a = a + \frac{ay+az}x$, for example? There are many solutions apart from $a=b=c=0$.

Comment: @Théophile How this problem has many solutions? I just conclude $ a= a+ \frac{ay+az}{x} $ to make him understand.. other wise we will conclude from equation, $ a+b+c (\frac{ay+az}{x} + \frac{bx+z}{y} + \frac{cx+cy}{z}) = a+b+c $ . we will get $ \frac{ay+az}{x} + \frac{bx+z}{y} + \frac{cx+cy}{z}=0 $ we can't make $ x,y,z \in {0} $.

Comment: Here's a nice integer solution: $$\frac1{-1}+\frac21+\frac33 = \frac{1+2+3}{-1+1+3}.$$ To see that there are many more solutions, fix $a,b,c,z,t$, for example. You now have two equations in $x$ and $y$: one is effectively a hyperbola, and the other, a line. I encourage you to graph this to see what happens.

Comment: Or, if you like, take your last equation and multiply by $xyz$. This gives $ayz(y+z)+bxz(x+z)+cxy(x+y)=0$. Again, fix $a,b,c,z$. You now have a curve in $x,y$. (And again, I encourage you to graph this to see for yourself.)